# What is your biggest problem as an English language learner?

Tags: meaning

I'm curious to know what people think are their biggest problems when learning English. Let's answer these questions.

1. What is your biggest problem as an English language learner?
2. How would it make a difference if there was a good solution to your problem?
3. How difficult is it currently to find a good solution to your problem?

Comment: This question is off topic for both [ell.se] and [meta]. This is not a discussion forum, it is a question and answer site. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use of present perfect continuous and the the difference between present perfect simple and  continuous in specific situations. You can't find the answers in one book, you have to collect the information from different sources, but first you have to find the source. That can be quite frustrating sometimes. What's more, people do not always agree. One says one thing, the other something else.
2. I wouldn't spend so much time looking for answers.
3. Difficult. It takes a lot of searching on the internet, reading books and asking questions on this forum. So far it has taken me about 18 months. You have to be patient and persistent.

Answer (score 1):

1. The verb tense is very hard for me since my first language is Chinese, which does not have verb tense at all.
2. If there is a good solution to this situation, then it could save me lots of time from learning English.
3. It is hard to memorize all verb tense and their usage.